# $http.get messing JSON parameters

Tags: json, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I'm comunicating my Rails API with my AngularJS application.
Everything is working great and normal up until the point I have to **send parameters in a GET request**. This is the Rails controller

```
def cats
  if cat_params[:color]
    @cats = Cat.where(... #you know
  else
    //Do something else
  end

private
  def cat_params
    params.require(:cat).permit(:color)
  end
```

Then from Angular

```
 var kitty = {
   cat: {
     color: "red"
   }
 }
 $http.get('some URL', { params: kitty }).success.....
```

By this time, the params hash looks like a stringify JSON

```
Started GET "some URL?cat=%7B%22color%22:%22red%22%7D" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-28 23:10:24 -0300
Processing by Some_controller as JSON
  Parameters: {"cat"=>"{\"color\":\"red\"}", "cat_id"=>"19"}
  Cat Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "cat".* FROM "cats"  WHERE "cat"."id" = 19 LIMIT 1
  {"cat"=>"{\"color\":\"red\"}", "format"=>"json", "controller"=>"some_controller", "action"=>"some_action", "cat_id"=>"19"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 95ms

NoMethodError - undefined method `permit' for "{\"cat\":\"red\"}":String:
```

I'm also sending the `Content-Type` header, set to `'application/json'`.
From Angular's $http.get documentation, I read that if the value of `params` is something other than a string, it will stringify the JSON object, so the issue is not in the front-end.

I don't think the solution begins with starting JSON parsing the params hash, since I've had no need to do it in the past. It seems to me that `strong_parameters` is playing dirty, or Rails is ignoring the JSON string. Any ideas what to do next?

Comment: Can you not modify your method type to POST and post the JSON data instead?

Comment: Yes, @ThiagoPXP, but the method does not creates nor stores new information to the database. It wouldn't be correct to change to POST.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same issue. Changing the [param serializer](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike) solved the issue for me:

```
$http.get('someURL', {
  paramSerializer: '$httpParamSerializerJQLike',
  params: {cat: {color: 'red}}
})
```

Also adding the `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` header will not help since it applies to the the body the request.

Answer (score 0):

I used to meet a `$http.get` problem that when call `$http.get('some url', {params:SOME_PARAMS})`, `SOME_PARAMS` could be transformd to key-value params when it is a simple key-value data like `{color:'red'}`, and it would transform params to json string when it is a complex type like `{cat:{color:'red'}}`.

So to solve your question, I suggest that add params behind url like:

```
 $http.get('some URL?cat[color]=red').success.....
```

Comment: Yes, I already tried with that, but the API works with the 'complex' form of the JSON.